# What is the meaning of the assembly output of the new operator?

Tags: c++

The `new` operator returns the address of some newly allocated memory from the heap to hold some data until it is no longer needed.

Using GCC, I stopped the compiler immediately after preprocessing and compilation proper, and this is the assembly code generated.

**What (if anything) does the compiler generate in order to request memory dynamically?**

**Since memory management is handled by the OS, there must be some platform + CPU specific processes happening; when does the process transition from platform independent (source code) to dependent (memory management, executable, etc.)?**

**C++**

```cpp
int main()
{
    int* x = new int;
}
```

**Assembly**

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
.LFB0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    movl    $4, %ecx
    call    _Znwy
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .ident  "GCC: (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.2.0"
    .def    _Znwy;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Comment: "Since memory management is handled by the OS..." - where did you get this assumption?

Comment: "Since memory management is handled by the OS" - not true for calls to `new` in general. The C++ runtime will typically request a block of memory from the OS that `new` then parcels out to you.

Comment: Your impletation *may* request memory from the OS *or* it may return memory from an internal pool/allocator. You, as a C++ program, cannot know and shouldn't need to care. And when you return that memory it *may* go back to the OS or it *may* just go back into your implementations pool, to be reused later.

Comment: Memory management **within a C++ application** is handled by the C++ runtime library. In the disassembly, that's `call _Znwy`, i.e., a call to the function `operator new`. It's up to the runtime library to handle dealing with the OS.

Comment: @AnT Honestly, I just guessed.